# onClick function not working

Tags: android, button, onclick

I am having problems with a button, I'm trying to set it on SetOnClickListener function, and tells it what to do when onClick, but it's giving me error messages that I can't figure out why.

I keep on getting these error messages:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete 
     MethodBody
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete

Here's the code:

```
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(this, "The Amount a Person has to pay: $" + result,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
```

Thank you for all of your kind feedbacks

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. You have a syntax error further up.

Answer (score 0):

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Answer (score 0):

change this line
Toast.makeText(this, "The Amount a Person has to pay: $" + result,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

to

Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "The Amount a Person has to pay: $" + result,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }